# Calling an onclick javascript event after a form submit

Tags: php, javascript, form-submit

I have a radio button in my html form and I have assigned a javascript onclick function to disable a few form text field. But after form submit, I am unable to keep the disabled form text fields in disabled state. It is changing back to normal textbox.

So I need to call the onclick function again to keep the previously disabled field in disabled state after form submission. I am able to keep the exact radio button checked using a php echo `' checked="checked"'`, but how can I call the javascript onclick function as well  ? (without using ajax)

radio button code:

```
<input onclick="show_textarea_1()" type="radio" name="button" value="Text Area 1" <?php if (isset($_POST['button']) && $_POST['button'] == 'Text Area 1')  echo ' checked="checked"';?> />Text Area 1
```

show_textarea_1() function:

```
function show_textarea_1()
   {
    $('#textarea2').attr("disabled","disabled");
    $('#textarea1').removeAttr("disabled"); 

  }
```

Comment: try with html....<input type="text" disabled> .. then u can use jquery function to remove it whenever neccessary

Comment: @ Ganesh       : I am disabling the field depends upon the radio button. So I think I can not go with above method

Comment: The best way you can do here is to ensure that the button is checked during page reload. In jQuery there is a function called .trigger() which ensures you to get your radio button clicked on page load. I think this may help you..http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Answer (score 0):

why not...

```
<textarea id="textarea1" <?=((isset($_POST['button']) && $_POST['button'] == 'Text Area 1') ? '' : 'disabled')?>></textarea>
```

That should work.